# How to change URL structure for pagination pages?

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules, paginate-links

Hi I'm new to WordPress hence if my question was simple or stupid I'm sorry, but please someone tell me how to change URL for pagination pages.

Currently I'm having URL for pagination pages as:

```
www.example.com/category_name.html/1
www.example.com/category_name.html/2
www.example.com/category_name.html/3
```

etc.

But I need to change this URL structure as:

```
www.example.com/category_name.html?page=1
www.example.com/category_name.html?page=2
www.example.com/category_name.html?page=3
```

etc.

I tried something like this but it's not working.

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_author_rules' );
function add_author_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        "bycategory/108-abodes-of-vishnu)/?$",
        "category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]",
        "top");
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `format` argument of `wp_link_pages` function like this:

```
<?php $args = array(
  'base'               => '%_%',
  'format'             => '?page=%#%',
  'total'              => 1,
  'current'            => 0,
  'show_all'           => False,
  'end_size'           => 1,
  'mid_size'           => 2,
  'prev_next'          => True,
  'prev_text'          => __('« Previous'),
  'next_text'          => __('Next »'),
  'type'               => 'plain',
  'add_args'           => False,
  'add_fragment'       => '',
  'before_page_number' => '',
  'after_page_number'  => ''
); ?>

<div class="pagelink"><?php echo paginate_links( $args ); ?></div>
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. Can you please tell me is there any other way I can do?