# Custom pagination structure

Tags: wp-redirect, template-redirect

Currently my pagination works like

```
http://example.com/city/usa/                     #for page 1
http://example.com/city/usa/page/2
http://example.com/city/usa/page/3    ...and so on
```

I want to change it to:

```
http://example.com/city/usa/                         #for page 1
http://example.com/city/usa/page2
http://example.com/city/usa/page3
```

I am using [wp-pagenavi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) plugin.

What I have tried:
[option1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/275527/paginate-links-ignore-my-format) 
[option2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/212507/how-to-change-url-structure-for-pagination-pages) 
[option3](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)

What is the issue:
If I access URL with `.../page5` (or any page) then it redirects to `.../page/5/`

Answer (score 2):

After searching here and there, probably I found solution. (Don't know if I am doing wrong in WP terminology!)

Page was redirecting from `.../page5` to `.../page/5`, because of `redirect_canonical` function resides in Wordpress core.

So I further searched for altering it by `hook`.

[Few people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34756836/prevent-wordpress-home-page-redirect-after-wp-4-4-1) were saying remove `redirect_canonical` filter by adding this in code: `remove_filter('template_redirect','redirect_canonical');`.

But, after checking some [other answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144937/disable-only-url-auto-complete-not-the-whole-canonical-url-system/144970#144970), I think I have to correct only my case, as removing whole `redirect_canonical` filter cause trouble in other part of Wordpress.

Here is my final code which was added in my theme's `functions.php`

```
function remove_page_number_permalink_redirect( $redirect_url )
{
    if (is_paged() && get_query_var('paged') > 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return $redirect_url;
}
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'remove_page_number_permalink_redirect' );
```